# Ruby net/imap login not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imap

Can't figure out why since the structure seem very straightforward

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new("imap.gmail.com", 993, ssl: true)
imap.login("someuser@gmail.com", "someValidPassword")
```

returns this error

```
Net::IMAP::NoResponseError:  Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
from /Users/Rocco/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/imap.rb:1171:in `get_tagged_response'
```

I have imap enabled in my gmail, I'm working locally but through a web tunnel (i.e. I could send you the url and you'd be able to access it) so it shouldn't be that different than working in production. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: happens for yahoo as well

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new("imap.mail.yahoo.com", 993, true, nil, false)
imap.login("myAccount@yahoo.com", "myPassword")
```

Same error

```
Net::IMAP::NoResponseError:  (#MBR1240) Please verify your account by going to https://login.yahoo.com
from /Users/Rocco/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/imap.rb:1171:in `get_tagged_response'
from /Users/Rocco/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/imap.rb:1225:in `block in send_command'
from /Users/Rocco/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /Users/Rocco/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/imap.rb:1207:in `send_command'
from /Users/Rocco/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/imap.rb:435:in `login'
from (irb):8
from /Users/Rocco/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail has fickle and unpredictable login protection. It may block you for any reason Google sees fit.

There are a couple things you can do:

You can either try to go to the web user interface, or the [Unlock Captcha](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) page *from the same IP it sees you connecting from* to unlock it.

You can try turning on [Less Secure Apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255).

You can implement full [OAUTH2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Depending on your login settings (eg, if you have two factor turned on), you may be able to generate an [App Specific Password](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) which should also work.

Comment: Thanks but it happens for Yahoo as well with the same error. Added above.

Comment: It is not the same error.  The text is different.  However, Yahoo also has login protection, and Yahoo is even more difficult to work around.  Implementing OAUTH2 is a surefire way to get Gmail to work, but I know no workaround for Yahoo.

Comment: For Yahoo, you may get it to work by going to the URL in the error message, again, from the same IP you're trying to log in from.

Comment: hmm ok I'll look into doing OAUTH2 for gmail. Last question, do you know of any workarounds for iCloud accounts?

Comment: For icloud, App Specific Passwords seem to work well.   You can generate them at appleid.apple.com, but that may only be available if you have 2FA turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, for me helped Unlock Captcha, i use nginx to forward request from my browser through vps server to google.

```
  location /fo {
    proxy_pass https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha;
  }
```

Comment: I think you can clarify/improve your answer? The question asks a potential issue about Ruby code. The code in your answer is not in Ruby and so it is not trivial to see how it is related to the question.